# DataSource connected from Interface Builder returns nil in initializer

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, interface-builder

I have implemented a dataSource for my custom UIControl, and connected it to it's view controller through Interface Builder. In the initializer, I need to access it to set my views. I call it like so:

```
required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false   // Ensure Auto Layout is on
    setGestureRecognizers()

    labels = createButtons(dataSource.data)
...

}
```

The application crashes, complaining that dataSource is nil.

Comment: Which initializer are you doing this in?

Comment: init(coder: aDecoder)

Comment: The viewController was instantiated through the storyboard. It is the storyboard entry point.

Comment: Are you accessing it before or after you all `super.init(coder:aDecoder)` ?

Comment: I am accessing the dataSource (view controller) from the custom UIControl after super.init(coder:aDecoder) was called within the UIControl's init(coder:aDecoder)

Comment: is dataSource nil or is dataSource.data nil? It looks like you need your to be control able to respond to changes in data and handle the fact that data may not be available initially

Comment: dataSource is nil. dataSource.data is not an optional.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access `IBOutlet` references (or anything configured in the storyboard) during `init`. This should be deferred until `viewDidLoad`.

The *View Controller Programming Guide* used to have a nice discussion on this topic. It included a flow chart that described how outlets are not hooked up when the view controller is first instantiated, but only later in the process, and can only be safely accessed in `viewDidLoad` (or later in the process, such as some of the appearance methods), but not `init`.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I needed to create loadView() function for my custom control to be called in the view controller's viewDidLoad function

Comment: @jjatie - Only implement `loadView` if you are programmatically instantiating your view controller's views. Otherwise let the storyboard or NIB do it's job, and put your initialization logic dependent upon that storyboard/NIB in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: `loadView` is within the UIControl, not an override of `viewController.loadView()`. Perhaps I could name that better though.

Comment: @jjatie - If you want to do initialization of a control after it's been loaded by a storyboard/NIB, you do this in `awakeFromNIB`. The point is that you cannot do this in `init` of the control. If doing this in view controller, you put this in `viewDidLoad`. If you're doing this within `UIControl` (or `UIView`) subclass, you have to put this in a method that is called by the OS when the control is loaded by the storyboard/NIB (such as `awakeFromNIB`).

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems like an appropriate answer to my question. Repost and I'll accept your answer.